# CSS: Usings IDs for Single Web Page

Tags: css

I know there are debates on whether or not to use ids in css, but I have a situation where it may make more sense to use ids.  If you have a site with a header and nav bar that never changes and all content is loaded in a div dynamically with js, why wouldn't you use ids for the header and nav bar?

Comment: What debate is there for whether or not to use `id`s?

Comment: The debates typically end with "it depends". So, it sounds like in your case, IDs might make sense. Just know that if there is **ever** some module on that same page that needs the same styles as what you've applied to an ID, that element will need a unique ID. If you're not sure what the big deal with using IDs is then google CSS Specificity and you'll get the picture.

Comment: Use IDs where ever appropriate, there is no debate.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about `id` is that there can only be one. `class` can be unlimited.

So if you have something that will never change, it's okay to use ID.

**However**, it's better to use classes when you can.

One thing I see a lot with new web programmers is *heavy* overuse of IDs, when there is no sense in it.

Header, Nav, fine, assign an id if you want, but you could just as easily use a class and re-use it later on (as in the case of nav, say class `menu`) - then you could have another at the bottom of the page without conflicting IDs.

There is no debate. Just best practices and keeping code simple and readable.

Comment: Another bad answer, it's better to use IDs when you can, not the other way around.

Comment: @Nit Better to use IDs? Have you heard of specificity? There isn't "better" or "worse". Develop with the requirements of the project.

Comment: Leaving aside how you group things in general, using a class when you should be using an id is wrong, that's my point. The performance loss is large, especially on large pages.

Comment: @kcdwayne no need for name calling. Also, your answer does not take into account CSS specificity.

Comment: *The performance loss is large, especially on large pages* - you should substantiate such claims with evidence. There's not a huge performance hit whether you use classes or id - that being said, ID's usually *add* code *(size)* to the file because it takes more characters to make it so - a lot of it repeated. I'm not here to argue. The question has been answered.

Comment: You're shifting the burden of proof – you made the claim that it's better to use classes. But in all honesty, look up any basic CSS performance guides and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: The performance impact is **not** that large, milliseconds compared to hours in deciphering someones God-awful slung together coding. Yes ID's are technically "faster" from a DOM parsing POV, next being tagname, 3rd being classes. The answer, IMO, goes beyond that to *readability* and just plain common sense. I see too many pages with divitis and a slew of unneeded IDs that could easily have been handled with a few classes. It's ridged, adds actual file size from the extra lines of code, and just plain ugly. http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

From [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2):

> The id attribute assigns a unique identifier to an element (which may
>   be verified by an SGML parser). For example, the following paragraphs
>   are distinguished by their id values:
>
> `<P id="myparagraph"> This is a uniquely named paragraph.</P>`
>
> `<P> id="yourparagraph"> This is also a uniquely named paragraph.</P>`
>
> The id attribute has several roles in HTML:
>
> ```
> As a style sheet selector.
> As a target anchor for hypertext links.
> As a means to reference a particular element from a script.
> As the name of a declared OBJECT element.
> For general purpose processing by user agents (e.g. for identifying fields when extracting data from HTML pages into a database, translating HTML documents into other formats, etc.).
> ```

And if you want to know more about class :

> The class attribute, on the other hand, assigns one or more class
>   names to an element; the element may be said to belong to these
>   classes. A class name may be shared by several element instances. The
>   class attribute has several roles in HTML:
>
> ```
> As a style sheet selector (when an author wishes to assign style information to a set of elements).
> For general purpose processing by user agents.
> ```
>
> In the following example, the SPAN element is used in conjunction with
>   the id and class attributes to markup document messages. Messages
>   appear in both English and French versions.

```
<!-- English messages -->
<P><SPAN id="msg1" class="info" lang="en">Variable declared twice</SPAN>
<P><SPAN id="msg2" class="warning" lang="en">Undeclared variable</SPAN>
<P><SPAN id="msg3" class="error" lang="en">Bad syntax for variable name</SPAN>

<!-- French messages -->
<P><SPAN id="msg1" class="info" lang="fr">Variable d&eacute;clar&eacute;e deux fois</SPAN>
<P><SPAN id="msg2" class="warning" lang="fr">Variable ind&eacute;finie</SPAN>
<P><SPAN id="msg3" class="error" lang="fr">Erreur de syntaxe pour variable</SPAN>
```

> The following CSS style rules would tell visual user agents to display
>   informational messages in green, warning messages in yellow, and error
>   messages in red:

```
SPAN.info    { color: green }
SPAN.warning { color: yellow }
SPAN.error   { color: red }
```

> Note that the French "msg1" and the English "msg1" may not appear in
>   the same document since they share the same id value. Authors may make
>   further use of the id attribute to refine the presentation of
>   individual messages, make them target anchors, etc.
>
> Almost every HTML element may be assigned identifier and class
>   information.
>
> Suppose, for example, that we are writing a document about a
>   programming language. The document is to include a number of
>   preformatted examples. We use the PRE element to format the examples.
>   We also assign a background color (green) to all instances of the PRE
>   element belonging to the class "example".

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE>... document title ...</TITLE>
<STYLE type="text/css">
PRE.example { background : green }
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<PRE class="example" id="example-1">
...example code here...
</PRE>
</BODY>
```

> By setting the id attribute for this example, we can (1) create a
>   hyperlink to it and (2) override class style information with instance
>   style information.
>
> Note. The id attribute shares the same name space as the name
>   attribute when used for anchor names. Please consult the section on
>   anchors with id for more information.